# How does Android find out the url of the "Sign In" page of any Wi-Fi Network?

Tags: android, url, wifi, android-wifi

I'm noticing this for a while now, that often when my Wi-Fi is not working, my Android device is asking me to "Sign In" to that particular Wi-Fi network. It works flawlessly no matter which Wi-Fi network I'm connected to. Now I know that different ISPs have different Login pages and the url of all these pages are not the same. So, my question is, how does the Android OS find out the what's the url of the "Sign-In" page of the Wi-Fi network I'm connected to?

Any help regarding this query will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Android has no idea, the access point/network redirects you to its captive portal/login if you aren't authenticated.

Comment: @Collin Gillespie If Android has no idea then how does it figure out whether it is a ready to use network or if it requires signing in?

Comment: You have got it back to front, android is dumb. It just connects to the network and tries to use it. If the network decides you are not authorized it will force you to the login page regardless of what url you put in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     if (!url.getHost().equals(urlConnection.getURL().getHost())) {
       // we were redirected! Kick the user out to the browser to sign on?

     ...
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

Maybe you can find something here that does the work for you.
[HTTP URL Connection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)